# Laravel submit form from a tab and return to same tab in view

Tags: laravel

I have a view with multiple tabs. Each having different forms. When I submit a form from one tab, it returns to same page but primary tab. How could I get to return to same tab from which I was working.

**Controller**

```
public function recieve(Request $request)
    {        
        $item = Item::find($request->input('item'));
            $item->recieved_at = now();
            $item->recieved_status = "1";
            $item -> save();
        return redirect('/files/'.$item->file)->with('success','Item Recieved Confirmed');
    }
```

**view** - tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="fileTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab"
                   aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="true">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="job-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#job" role="tab" aria-controls="job"
                   aria-selected="false">Job</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="items-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#items" role="tab" aria-controls="items"
                   aria-selected="false">Items</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" id="mechanic-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#mechanic" role="tab"
                                    aria-controls="mechanic" aria-selected="false">Labour Hours</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="accounts-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#accounts" role="tab"
                   aria-controls="accounts" aria-selected="false">Accounts</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="accounts-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#preview" role="tab"
                   aria-controls="accounts" aria-selected="false">Print Preview</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Form

```
@if($file->job_status == "Closed")@else 
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'FilesController@item','method' => 'POST']) !!}
<div class="row pt-3 pb-1">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
        {{Form::text('part_number','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Part Number'])}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        {{Form::text('description','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Part Name'])}}                   
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
        {{Form::text('qty','',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Qty'])}}                 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2">
        {{Form::select('recieved_by',$users,null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}                   
    </div>
</div>
    {{Form::hidden('file',$file->id)}}
    {{Form::submit('Release Item',['class'=>'form-control btn-danger btn btn-sm'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}
@endif
```

I tried using hashtag tab name in return redirect statement,

```
return redirect('/files/'.$item->file."#items-tab")->with('success','Item Recieved Confirmed');
```

it would simply highlight the name but would not select. How could I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: I encountered this before, and i dont have any way on how to solve it. At the end of the day, I just used Ajax in submitting the form so that the page will not reload.

Comment: How do you navigate between tabs in the first place?

Comment: they are simple bootstrap tabs. So simply click the tab. All contents of all tabs is technically on the same page. Just classified as tabs.

Answer (score 3):

your tab navigation,

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabMenu" role="tablist">
        <li><a href="#Galleries" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i> Galleries</a></li>
</ul>
```

hidden input field for tab

```
<input type="hidden" name="tab" value="Galleries">
```

RedirectRoute

```
$tab = $request->get('tab');
return back()->withInput(['tab'=>$tab]);
```

Javascript,

```
<script>
        //redirect to specific tab
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tabMenu a[href="#{{ old('tab') }}"]').tab('show')
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in laravel than all you can do is,

-Give an id to each tab and an write an active class.

-Put a hidden input with value of the parent tab id.

-So, laravel will receive the tab id in the request object.

-Now, you can do whatever and return the tab id with to the view.

-Give a if condition to each tab item and check if matches the id from laravel response.

The match the id set the active class to it.

example

```
<ul>
  <li id='tab1 {{ session()->get('tabId') === 'tab1' ? 'active' : '' }}'></li>
  <li id='tab2 {{ session()->get('tabId') === 'tab2' ? 'active' : '' }}'></li>  
</ul>


  // tab1 body

  <form>
  <input type="hidden" name="tabId" value="tab1">
  ...
  </form>

  // tab2 body
  <form>
  <input type="hidden" name="tabId" value="tab2">
  ...
  </form>


  // controller
  public funciton(Request $request) {
  //tabId
  $tabId = $request->input('tabId')
  ....
  ....

  return redirect()->back()->with('tabId' => $tabId);    
  }
```

Comment: I can't write actual code as I dont know how your code looks like but I can give a prototype if you want. thanks

Comment: Please have a look, answer has been edit.
note: there might be syntax related error as I haven't tested it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

**Controller**:

```
public function tab() {
    $active_tab = "tab2";
    return view('tabs.index', compact('active_tab'));
}
```

**View**:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="@if($active_tab=="tab1") active @endif"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="@if($active_tab=="tab2") active @endif"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li class="@if($active_tab=="tab3") active @endif"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade @if($active_tab=="tab1") in active @endif">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Some content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade @if($active_tab=="tab2") in active @endif">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade @if($active_tab=="tab3") in active @endif">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Undefined variable: active_tab

Answer (score 0):

You can show a specific tab with this code:

```
function showTab(tab){
   $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};

// Verify location.hash
if (window.location.hash !== ''){
    showTab(window.location.hash);
}
```

But I would pass a query string in the return, just to make sure there will be no collision with other eventual hashes. Something like:

```
return redirect('/files/'.$item->file."?openTab=your-tab-id")->with('success','Item Recieved Confirmed');
```

Of course, you would change the "location.hash" verification to a query string verification. Example: https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript